# Setting up Root library on Visual Studios Express 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, physics, root-framework

I'm trying to incorporate CERN's data analysis libraries, ROOT, in my c++ code.

At the moment i'm using Visual Studio c++ 2010 Express. So far I think i've succeeded in creating a Property Sheet for the ROOT-library, i.e. I can include libraries and complile without getting any errors. The problem rises when I try to start my program. The console gives me the following error:

"Error in : libMathCore.dll does not exist in ... (lots of weird symbols)...or has wrong file extension (.dll)"

I only get the error whenever I include some ROOT-library.

Do any of you know why i get the error, how i fix it or another library for data analysis?

Answer (score 1):

The *libMathCore.dll* is in the bin directory of your *Root* installation. You have to copy it to your VS2010 project or your System file.